# How can type Null is not a subtype of type int be solved?

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to match a set of custom user data to a class I created like so:

```
ListView.builder(
        physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
        shrinkWrap: true,
        itemCount: recentCalls.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, int index) {
          return CallList(
            name: recentCalls[index].name,
            time: recentCalls[index].time,
            icon: recentCalls[index].icon,
            imageURL: recentCalls[index].imageURL,
          );
        },
      ),
```

This is supposed to be displayed on the UI but for some reason, I get this error message:

```
══════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'int'
The relevant error-causing widget was CallList
```

I am supposed to be able to be able to display the custom data on the screen to update the UI but it displays this error...

This is my `CallList class`:

```
class CallList extends StatefulWidget {
  const CallList({
    Key? key,
    required this.name,
    required this.time,
    required this.icon,
    required this.imageURL,
  }) : super(key: key);
  final String? name, time, imageURL;
  final IconData icon;

  @override
  _CallListState createState() => _CallListState();
}

class _CallListState extends State<CallList> {
  get index => null;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final ThemeData themeData = Theme.of(context);
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {},
      child: Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10, vertical: 16),
        child: Row(
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  CircleAvatar(
                    backgroundImage:
                        NetworkImage((recentCalls[index]).imageURL),
                    maxRadius: 30,
                  ),
                  Container(
                    color: Colors.transparent,
                    child: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Text(
                          "${widget.name}",
                          style: themeData.textTheme.headline6!.copyWith(
                            fontSize: 18,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                          ),
                        ),
                        addVertical(6),
                        Text(
                          "${widget.time}",
                          style: themeData.textTheme.bodyText1!.copyWith(
                            fontSize: 18,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  Center(
                    child: Icon(
                      widget.icon,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here I the list of calls:

```
List<UserCall> recentCalls = [
  UserCall(
    name: "Nathaniel",
    time: "08:00",
    imageURL: "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/13.jpg",
    icon: Icons.call_received_outlined,
  ),
  UserCall(
    name: "Chris",
    time: "08:07",
    imageURL: "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/13.jpg",
    icon: Icons.call_made_outlined,
  ),
  UserCall(
    name: "Samuel",
    time: "08:10",
    imageURL: "",
    icon: Icons.call_received_outlined,
  ),
  UserCall(
    name: "Damien",
    time: "08:50",
    imageURL: "",
    icon: Icons.call_made_outlined,
  ),
  UserCall(
    name: "Daniel",
    time: "10:00",
    imageURL: "",
    icon: Icons.call_received_outlined,
  ),
  UserCall(
    name: "Nathaniel",
    time: "11:47",
    imageURL: "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/12.jpg",
    icon: Icons.call_made_outlined,
  ),
  UserCall(
    name: "Samuel",
    time: "13:00",
    imageURL: "",
    icon: Icons.call_made_outlined,
  ),
  UserCall(
    name: "Ritchie",
    time: "Yesterday",
    imageURL: "",
    icon: Icons.call_made_outlined,
  ),
  UserCall(
    name: "Jonathan",
    time: "Yesterday",
    imageURL: "",
    icon: Icons.call_received_outlined,
  ),
  UserCall(
    name: "Nathaniel",
    time: "2 days ago",
    imageURL: "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/12.jpg",
    icon: Icons.call_received_outlined,
  ),
  UserCall(
    name: "Nathaniel",
    time: "08:00",
    imageURL: "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/12.jpg",
    icon: Icons.call_made_outlined,
  ),
];
```

How can I work around this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `CallList` class the value for the `index` getter always returns a value of `null`, however a `List` index is always to be a value type of type `int`, this is why you get the error.

Change the code below

```dart
CircleAvatar(
                    backgroundImage:
                        NetworkImage((recentCalls[index]).imageURL),
                    maxRadius: 30,
                  ),
```

to

```dart
CircleAvatar(
                    backgroundImage:
                        NetworkImage(widget.imageURL),
                    maxRadius: 30,
                  ),
```

Essentially replace the index look up with the field `imageURL` as defined in the widget. The index lookup is happening in the `ListView.builder` and so its not needed in the `CallListState` class